# Does it matter how thick the PCB is?

Tags: pcb

When it comes to placing order for manufacture of the PCB, one thing that can be chosen is the PCB thickness. I am talking about the PCB thickness other than what is added to it by copper layers and the prepreg that goes in between copper layers. I am talking about the core of board itself only.

Is there a reason why I would choose one thickness over another besides the fact that thicker board will bend less under stress? The layer stack from PCB manufacturer might require specifc board thickness to get the 50ohm characteristic impedance, but let's put that on side as well.

Why would I, for example, choose between 1.2mm and 2.0mm board?

Comment: Mechanical strength and impedance are common reasons to change the core thickness.

Comment: i find the thicker ones easier to hand-solder and that they run ICs a little cooler as there's more surface area on the plated through holes.

Comment: Are you sure you're talking about the core alone? When you get a 1.6 mm board, that's inclusive of all copper layers--they will use thinner core if you ask for thicker copper.

Comment: An ecological aspect is to use not more material than required.

Comment: The PCB sizes that are available are just a few and do not differ by a large degree (but do differ a lot if we look at % change e.g 1mm to 2mm means 100% thicker board) and its not like we are comparing a micron thick board with an inch thick board. But really, it seems that unless I am following specific impedance profile or the connector in encloser needs to be at certain distance from enclosure bottom, I guess I can use any size. It is not clear how much a thicker board will help in keeping ICs cooler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it matters, mechanically.

Assume that you have a PCB with some connectors for example, and you put it in a case. If the slots for connectors are made with the assumption that the PCB is 1.6mm thick, then 1.2mm or 2.0mm PCB will not work as the connectors are misplaced by 0.4mm.

Many interfaces such as ISA, PCI, PCIe and M.2 cards have a defined thickness and you can't plug in a PCB to a PCIe or M.2 socket if it does not have the correct board thickness.

Sometimes you define the thickness because of mechanical flexibility, or rigidness, based on how much you want the PCB to flex, or not to flex, depending on the application.

Comment: One more thing to add: Some through-hole components (certain RF connectors for example) might not have long enough pins or mounting posts to solder easily to an excessively thick board.

Answer (score 1):

If stiffness and trace impedance are not issues, perhaps a certain thickness is needed by other hardware, for example an edge connector, or a mounting slot in an enclosure..

Failing that thinner is usually less expensive, and also weighs less.

Does it matter how thick? only sometimes it does.

Answer (score 1):

Taking 1.6mm as a standard, I would use:

Thinner, when I want to use a 2-layer board for anything with slightly higher frequency like a switching converter or a 50 Ω trace.

Thicker, when the number of layers don't fit into 1.6 mm.

Answer (score 0):

Availability from suppliers. Not an issue with one or two sides board. It can be with multiple layer boards.

Comment: yes, I did assume that it would not matter for 2 layer boards.